# Oracle - Columns to Rows with headers

Tags: oracle, rows, multiple-columns

I have the below table and tried to use decode to switch from columns to rows but it is asking for group by clause.

```
PROD    SITE    L1                       L2
----    ----    --                       --
CSCO    LA     =< 5M , -.0001            =< 5M , .0001
IBM     LA     =< 5M , -.00005           =< 5M , .00005
IBM     NY     =< 1M , -.002             =< 1M , -.002
GOOG    LA     =< 2M , -.001             =< 2M , -.001
```

Trying to switch to as below. You see the "SITE" name goes to the header.

```
PROD    LA-L1            LA-L2             NY-L1           NY-L2         
----    -----            -----             -----           -----
CSCO    =< 5M , -.0001  =< 5M , .0001               
IBM     =< 5M , -.00005 =< 5M , .00005   =< 1M , -.002   =< 1M , -.002      
GOOG    =< 2M , -.001   =< 2M , .001
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT R.PROD, 
    DECODE(R.SITE,'LA',R.L1) "LA-L1",
    DECODE(R.SITE,'LA',R.L2) "LA-L2",
    DECODE(R.SITE,'NY',R.L1) "NY-L1",
    DECODE(R.SITE,'NY',R.L2) "NY-L2"
    FROM RESULTS R
GROUP BY R.PROD)
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT R.PROD, 
         MAX(DECODE(R.SITE,'LA',R.L1)) "LA-L1", 
         MAX(DECODE(R.SITE,'LA',R.L2)) "LA-L2", 
         MAX(DECODE(R.SITE,'NY',R.L1)) "NY-L1", 
         MAX(DECODE(R.SITE,'NY',R.L2)) "NY-L2" 
  FROM RESULTS R 
  GROUP BY R.PROD) 
ORDER BY 1;
```

As you're grouping by PROD you need an aggregate function. I used MAX (it ignores NULLs)

Comment: Thanks ! Didn't know that MAX could do the magic :) Works perfectly.